# Exclude main blog from get_blogs_of_user

Tags: multisite, user-meta, id, terms

I use WordPress Multisite and in the sidebar i have a box that shows a list of blogs the logged in user is a member of.

I'm looking for a way to exclude the mainblog from this list.
The main blog ID is 1

**Here is parts of the code I use:**

```
<?php // Gets user-info ?>
<?php global $current_user; get_currentuserinfo(); 
     $user_info = get_userdata(1); 
     $user_id = $current_user->ID; 
?> 

<?php // start the loop ?>
<?php $user_blogs = get_blogs_of_user( $user_id ); echo '<div>'; foreach ($user_blogs AS $user_blog) { echo '';?>

<?php // lists user blogs ?>
<?php echo ''.$user_blog->blogname.' '; ?>
```

Can anyone help me? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you drop this line in your code, you will see all the properties of $user_blogs.
`echo '<pre>'.print_r($user_blogs,true).'</pre>';`

One of them is `userblog_id`, so you just have to check against it before echoing the blogname.

```
<?php 
$user_blogs = get_blogs_of_user( $user_id ); 
if (!$user_blogs) {
    echo 'no blogs';
} else {
    echo '<div><ul>'; 
    foreach ( $user_blogs as $user_blog ) {
        if ( $user_blog->userblog_id != get_current_blog_id() ) { 
            echo '<li>' . $user_blog->blogname . '</li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ul></div>'; 
}
```

Comment: it does list blogs without id 1, but it also loops blog nr 1. So if I want to wrap a <li>your code</li> around it it leaves an empty list in the start. Shouldnt the id 1 be excluded in the loop code?

Comment: You are only gonna print an empty list item if you want to. I extended my example to make this clearer. You could [remove the array item](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) where the blog id equal 1 *before doing* the `foreach`, but I don't think it's worth the trouble.

Comment: you did it my friend. Missing a ' in the end </li> there, but perfect!! this was really helpful to me :) thanks!

Comment: ok, I have another challange. Is it possible to as an "else" if the user has no blogs?. It would be great to ass a text i.e. "You dont have any blogs yet. Click here to create one"

Comment: Added to the code, have phun..!